# Meaning of integrating a min function

Tags: probability, integration

In the following problem, I am given that $X\sim \exp(1)$ and $Y=\min(X,m)$ where $m$ is a positive number.

I am given the solution, but conceptually there are aspects of this that are very confusing to me

Taking into consideration that it will be undefined at $t=1$, I am to set up the problem  as

$$\int e^{t(\min(X,m)}=\int_0^me^{tx}\cdot e^{-x}dx+\int_m^\infty e^{tm}\cdot e^{-x}dx$$ for $t\neq 1$,

and for $t=1$:    $$M_Y(1)=\int e^{(\min(X,m)}dx=\int_0^m e^x\cdot e^{-x}dx+\int_{m}^{\infty} e^m\cdot e^{-x}dx ~ .$$

Solving this is straightforward enough. My questions are:

1. Conceptually, what is meant by integrating a min function? aIs it that on the left-hand side integral we are considering when X is less than m (and so the min) and on the right side, when m is less than X, (and so the min)?
2. On the righthand side, why do we have $\int_m^\infty e^{tm}\cdot e^{-x}dx$, and not $\int_m^\infty e^{tx}\cdot e^{-x}dx$ ?

Answer (score 1):

$$\min(m,x)=\begin{cases}x\le m\to x,\\x\ge m\to m\end{cases}$$

so that

$$\int_0^\infty f(\min(x,m))\,dx=\int_0^m f(x)\,dx+\int_m^\infty f(m)\,dx.$$

Answer (score 0):

**partial answer**

**(2)**

when you are integrating with limits $0$ to $m$ this means that you are considering $x\in [0,m]$ and this means that $x\leq m$ and thus $\min(x,m)=x$. now for the remaining interval $[m, +\infty)$, using similar reasoning, $\min(x,m)=m$. does this make sense?

Comment: Kind of, the lefthand side does make sense. However, the righthand side is still confusing for me. I would have thought that right hand side, that is interval $(m,\infty)$ would be to tell me about $\min(X,m)=m$. Does any part of our integration account for this?

Comment: yes you're right! sorry about the typo. i fixed it